# CodeIgniter Pagination links format

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using codeigniter's default pagination

```
< 1 2 3 4 >
```

but I'd like to make it to this format

```
< 1-10 11-20 21-30 >
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Question: You will need to extend code `system/CI_Pagination.php` library into `application/library/MY_Pagination.php`

Math Calculation by @Dan is fine, setup into `CI` Pagination Library, see below

1) Create file into `application/library/MY_Pagination.php` [**`more info`**](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) about Create Library

Overwrite `create_links()` method from custom method, see below

**Revised code** section in `create_links()` method

```
if ($this->cur_page === $loop){
    // Current page
    $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.($this->cur_page == 1 ? $loop : $loop*($this->per_page)+1).'-'.($loop * $this->per_page).$this->cur_tag_close;
}elseif ($i === $base_page){
 // First page
    $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a href="'.$first_url.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('start').'>'
               .((($loop)*($this->per_page) - $this->per_page)+1) .'-'. ($loop * $this->per_page).'</a>'
               .$this->num_tag_close;
}else{
     $append = $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix;
     $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a href="'.$base_url.$append.'"'.$attributes.$this->_attr_rel('start').'>'
               .((($loop)*($this->per_page) - $this->per_page)+1) .'-'. ($loop * $this->per_page)
               .'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
}
```

Full **MY_Pagination.php** file Line no(577-592) [**click here**](https://eval.in/184620)

**NOTE** I have used latest core file so please use you amendment in your current file

Comment: isn't this supposed to be in core/MY_Pagination.php?

Comment: `application/library/MY_Pagination.php` create new file.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function segment() on a non-object in /usr/local/www/game-yoyaku.atwiki/htdocs/application/libraries/MY_Pagination.php on line 125

Comment: did you copy `create_link()` method from own `system/CI_pagination.php` file? you must be old version of `CI` so you should use their own file (`system/CI_pagination.php`) code

Comment: yep.. I fixed the problem how ever it shows wrong paging

Comment: i am calling it from the controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60157/discussion-between-emil-rena-enriquez-and-girish).

Answer (score 1):

Do some simple math to adjust, so for example if `$x = 1`

Instead of page 1 being $x page 1 is:

```
<?php echo $x.'-'.($x * 10); ?>
```

Page 2 and higher is:

```
<?php 
    $x++;
    echo (($x)*10)-10)+1.'-'.($x * 10);
?>
```

Where `$x++` counts up for each display.

Comment: no... it's not possible with `CodeIgniter` library while `OP` won't modify library

Comment: Should be possible.  OP is just asking about the display, the value passed to URI on click can be distinct from what is displayed. As mentioned [in the docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) it is "100% customizable".

Comment: page link is creating by `create_link` function, he will need to extend library into `application/library/MY_Pagination.php` and overwrite method by custom method there custom code integrated, for more info https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: yeah so basically how do I do that using CI?

Comment: @Girish how will I be able to modify thos links? what config option should I change?

Comment: @EmilReñaEnriquez ,please see answer, keep same config as using currently

Comment: @Girish sorry I was logged out.. 

it worked however link is wrong 

it lacks /

for example www.somoething.com/asdf/20

it outputs www.something.com/asdf20

Comment: @EmilReñaEnriquez suppose this is part of `$config['base_url'] = base_url().'pc/r/ios/daily';` paging library config

Comment: @Girish I encountered another bug with the code again... if there are more than 2 links it shows wrong numbers for active link